# Is there a way to calculate the percentage CPU utilization by reading /proc/stat at once?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I guess the question is, could I somehow calculate the CPU utilization percentage just by reading the /proc/stat once?

```
# head -1 /proc/stat
cpu  67891300 39035 6949171 2849641614 118251644 365498 2341854 0
```

I am thinking about summarizing the columns except the IOWait (I was reading somewhere that it is counted in the idle) and that would give me the 100% and each individual column could be turned into percentage by (column/100_percent)*100.

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: twiddling thumbs
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs
- steal: involuntary wait
- guest: running a normal guest
- guest_nice: running a niced guest

Is this a viable approach or i am totally off the track?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track, `top` uses this file for this purpose. But you need to read it more than once.

Utilization is a is a measure of use over time. You can read it once providing you know the uptime in seconds of the host, then divide by that, but that would give you a utility rate of the host since the machine was booted.

If you want a rate over 5 seconds, you would read the file once, sleep for 5 seconds, read it again, obtain the difference of the calculations and divide by 5.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is correct. You can use /proc/stat as raw data and feed for example rrdtool with it.
I've done myself something like this so I know 100% it is possible.
You can nicely then graph the whole system load or each core individually.

**Here is a working example of my own:**
[image]

**Reassuming -> You can do it, it is not hard just basic mathematics and my graphs are a live example of that.** For collecting data I do a snapshot of /proc/stat to a temporary file localted on ramdisk and then I parse that file to collect data every 1 minute.

how I parse the data (fragment of bash script):

```
cat=/bin/cat # others defined the same way
......

$cat /proc/stat > /ramdisk/tmp/stat

ssCpuRawUser=`$cat /ramdisk/tmp/stat|$grep "cpu " | $awk '{print $2}'`
ssCpuRawNice=`$cat /ramdisk/tmp/stat|$grep "cpu " | $awk '{print $3}'`
    #other columns follow ....... 

#the most important there is that it is an incrementing COUNTER.
if [ ! -f ${data_dir}/sys.cpu.rrd ];then
        $rrdtool create ${data_dir}/sys.cpu.rrd -s 60 \
        DS:ssCpuRawUser:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawNice:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawSystem:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawIdle:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawIOwait:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawIRQ:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
        DS:ssCpuRawSoftIRQ:COUNTER:300:0:1250000 \
            RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:532800

fi

$rrdtool update ${data_dir}/sys.cpu.rrd N:$ssCpuRawUser:$ssCpuRawNice:$ssCpuRawSystem:$ssCpuRawIdle:$ssCpuRawIOwait:$ssCpuRawIRQ:$ssCpuRawSoftIRQ

# then in a loop each core the same way until all are parsed.
```

after You get data into the rrd database You can graph and sky is the limit :) http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html

Comment: How do you parse the data?

Comment: @ewwhite -> I edited my answer to show how I parse the data.

Comment: Beautiful graphs!  Regarding your missing column annotation: http://askubuntu.com/a/120961/451886.  If it's running in a VM, maybe it's the  "steal" counter.

Comment: +1 for rrdtool and ramdisk!

Answer (score 4):

If you want oneliner it may looks like this:

```
echo $(echo '100'; echo $(echo '(';head -1 /proc/stat | awk '{print $5}'; sleep 1; echo '-';head -1 /proc/stat |  awk '{print $5}';echo ')/100') | bc -l) | bc -l
```

The result: `97.17000000000000000000`

How it works:

```
echo $(echo '(';head -1 /proc/stat | awk '{print $5}'; sleep 1; echo '-';head -1 /proc/stat |  awk '{print $5}';echo ')/100')
```

produces `( 1055057784 - 1055058055 )/100` then this line feed to bc. Will have something like `-7.84000000000000000000`, then just wrap it up to `100-$(value)` and feed to bc again

There: 
`sleep #` - 1 second delay, if you change this value then the intermediate result should be divided to the number of seconds.
`$5` - 5th field, according to `man proc` and http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

Please let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're happy with just two digits after the point awk can do it all a lot simpler and more readable:

```
 awk -v oldidle=$(awk '/cpu / {print $5}' /proc/stat; sleep 1) '/cpu / {perc=100-($5-oldidle)/100 ; printf "%s", perc}' /proc/stat
```